# Do we know how Predacons fare against Dinobots in a fight?

Tags: transformers, dinobots

Prefers the Aligned Continuity.

Predacons are prehistoric now-extinct Cybertronians who, as their present-day clones attest, are very powerful physically and possibly indestructible by conventional means accessible to most Autobots or Decepticons.

Dinobots are the result of Shockwave's lab experiments on some Autobot captives during the War for Cybertron. They are also very powerful physically and difficult to take down.

When discussing the reappearance of Predacons in *Transformers: Prime*, Ironhide comments that Predacons are a "totally different thing" from Dinobots, in a tone that implies they are a greater threat than that. However, it should be noted that Predacons have been extinct and do not exist in living Cybertronian memory, so myths about the Predacons' power may have been exagerrated. Where the Predacons did make an appearance, they did display incredible physical prowess against regular-sized Autobots and Decepticons alike, yet we have not seen them up against the more powerful Dinobots.

Both Predacons and Dinobots prefer to fight in their strong, brutish beast forms. Do we have any indication on how exactly the two would fare if they are to clash head-on?

**Edit**: Just in case, I'd like to clarify that I'm not simply asking "Are Predacons more powerful than Dinobots?" Left as it is, such a question would be open to speculation. Specifically, I'm asking if we've any *official information* that would give an indication, direct or indirect. In other words, I'm not looking for speculation not based on official sources.

Comment: I don't follow Transformers, but I remember in Beast Wars and it's sequel series there are instances that where the ancient bots interact in some way with the modern ones. Not sure if there is direct conflict between the two but that is where i'd begin looking for the answer of how they stack up if Dinobots and predacons never interact.

Comment: That's a different story. The main Transformers in Beast Wars are Optimals & Predacons who are Autobots & Decepticons from a future where Cybertronian society shifted to more energy efficient beast forms, transported back in time to the prehistoric past, and encountering their G1 vehicular ancestors. My question looks at a completely different context, dating to after Hasbro's equivalent of Disney rebooting the Star Wars canon timeline.